# ¿Como colocar 2 elementos o mas dentro de un td?

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy intentando colocar 2 elementos dentro de un `td`
de momento utilizo 2 `button` pero pueden ser cualquier otro elemento

**Los elementos deben estar centralizados**

una forma que logre hacerlo es creando otro `table` dentro de `td`, que por lo visto no se puede insertar otro `tr`dentro de un `td`.

pero hay 2 problemas con esto

1. No se centralizan los elementos.
2. Se ve claramente que es una tabla dentro de otra lo cual no quiero que se vea.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-content: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
    <td><table><tr><td><Button>a</Button></td><td><Button>b</Button></td></tr></table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
</tbody>
  
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Meter una tabla dentro de otra no es buena idea. El problema es que no estas usando la propiedad correcta, deberías poner `text-aling:center`

Comment: @blonfu Entonces solo coloco los `Button` sin crear la tabla ? me interesa hacerlo de la mejor manera posible o correcta

Comment: @blonfu probé solo colocando el ``text-align: center;` en el `style` dentro de `tr` al igual que en el `td` y colocando los `Button` aparecen muy juntos lo cual intento que se muestren separados

Comment: si quieres separarlos dales un poco de margen con la propiedad `margin`

Comment: Ok.. ya logre implementarlo tal cual lo queria muchas gracias, aun cuando la respuesta @JorgeGuz ayuda igual a resolver el problema la forma en la que lo hice es en base a lo que recomiendas, entonces no se sea correcto poner la otra como respuesta correcta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que como no has utilizado clases y si estilos on-page y on-line se trata de una tabla para algo parecido a una campaña de mailing o similar, por eso te pongo como ejemplo la soliución apliacando estilos en línea. Espero que te sea de ayuda:

```
<body>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-content: center;
}
</style>



<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
    <td><table style="
    border: none;
    /* empty-cells: hide; */
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
"><tbody><tr><td style="
    border: none;
"><button>a</button></td><td style="border: none;"><button>b</button></td></tr></tbody></table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero comenta @blonfu no es bueno meter una tabla dentro de otra hay forma de hacerlo sin crear una tabla? pero que aun a si los `Button` estén separados(no se muestren pegados) y centralizados

Answer (score 0):

a ver si te funciona esto.

```html
<TABLE BORDER>
 <TR>
  <TH>Primero</TH>
  <TH>Segundo</TH>
  <TH>Tercero</TH>
 </TR>
 <TR>
  <TD>Celda 1</TD>
      <TD>Celda 2</TD>
      <TD>Celda 3.1<br> Celda 3.2</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR>
  <TD>Celda 4</TD>
      <TD>celda 5<br>celda5.1 </TD>
      <TD>Celda 6</TD>
 </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Y para que se centren, tan simple como poner ALIGN=

```html
<TABLE BORDER>
 <TR>
     <TH>Primero</TH>
     <TH>Segundo</TH>
     <TH>Tercero</TH>
 </TR>
 <TR ALIGN=center>
     <TD>Todas aCentroCelda 2</TD>
     <TD>Tambien al centro<br> Centro doble</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR>
     <TD ALIGN=right>Alineado a la derecha</TD>
     <TD ALIGN=center>Alineado al centro</TD>
     <TD>Por defecto<br>Alineado a la izquierdat</TD>
 </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: El atributo align está desaconsejado hoy en día. Se debería usar CSS.